# FileNotFound exception after saving the file in the same program

Tags: java, android, android-studio, filepath, filenotfoundexception

I have a method that takes a picture and saves it. In the method that it saves the picture, it sets a string for the path using `image.getAbsolutePath()` after the image is saved. I write the path to a `.txt` file, and then read out in a later method to try to set it as a `bitmap` and then set it as a `Bitmap` for an `ImageButton`. When I invoke the commands to do so, it gives me the `FileNotFound` exception. I use `getExternalFilesDir()` to determine the path for all my files in the application. Using the same path I set, save and retrieve files throughout the whole application that work just fine for `.txt` files and their readers and writers.

Upon checking the same path saved through the Android Studio device file explorer, then picture is exactly where the String says it is. Checking on the phone itself, the picture also exists.

The picture is saved in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/files/Pictures/<filename>`. The file name is correct in the application, but the app can't find the file.

I've tried saving the picture in a different location, and it wasn't able to find it. I've tried hard-coding the path into the app and it still wasn't able to find the picture.

My goal for the code is that the images can be set in one instance of the application, but will be set on future instances without further interaction from the user.

Here's the code blocks in question (This may not be the most efficient way to do what I want to do, either, but that doesn't matter to me. "OOP" isn't a concern, either, but if you have any suggestions and want to walk me through something, I'd be happy to learn):

**InventoryActivity2.class** - A class I use to take and save the picture. The path is saved in a text file with the `currentPhotoPath` String. This part of the code works as expected, but I don't want it to be out of question in case the error happens here.

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPathFile = new File(image.getAbsolutePath());
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        catToText = MainActivity.rootPath+"/appdata/inv"+ bcR +"/inv0.txt";
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(catToText);
                fw.write(currentPhotoPath);
                fw.close();
                System.out.println("----PHOTO PATH RECORDED----");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("----PHOTO PATH NOT RECORDED----");
            }
        }else{
            currentPhotoPathFile.delete();
        }
    }
```

**ImageLoader.class** - Class called when opening the Inventory activities to try to set the image for the 9 `ImageButton`s in my application. It goes through 9 files reading the contents of the corresponding `inv0.txt` files. If the file is empty, it skips it. If not, it sets the contents (the path to the image) to a `File` (`myDataF') and that's where the`FileNotFound`error is encountered (printing out "FILE NOT FOUND" at the end of the`ImageLoader` class.

```
public void main() {

        int i;

        for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            final File myExternalFile = new File(MainActivity.rootPath + "/appdata/inv" + i + "/inv0.txt");
            String myData = "";
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String strLine;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    myData = myData + strLine + "\n";
                }
                br.close();
                in.close();
                fis.close();

                myDataF = new File(myData);

                if (myData.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("-------------------------------STRING EMPTY IN FILE " + i);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("-------------------------------STRING CONTAINS " + myData);
                    setImage(i, myDataF);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private void setImage(int i, File myDataF) throws IOException {
        if (myDataF.exists()) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(myDataF);
                    Bitmap bmp = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
                    System.out.println("ATTEMPTING TO SET BITMAP ON " + i);
                    InventoryActivity.getIbx().setImageBitmap(bmp);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("---------BITMAP SET FAILED, FILE SEEN---------");
                }
            }else{
            System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND");
        }
    }
}
```

I know that's a lot of information, but I'm trying to be thorough so that the issue can be resolved quickly.

Comment: `System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND");` Change to `System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND: {" + myDataF.getAbsolutePath() + "}");` And you will see that the file path ends with a "\n". (caused by  myData = myData + strLine + "\n";). You could better have checked if the file existed before calling setImage(). if ( myData.exists() ) {....}. Further: if the text file contains two lines?

Comment: So the solution is an extra statement `myData = myData.trim();` after close() statement.

Comment: The way the writer is set up it will only ever have one line, the path itself. But you were exactly correct, I don't know how I missed the /n! Thank you!